# MongoDB: query alternative for deep embedded documents?

Tags: mongodb

I have this document in my mongoDB:

```
/* 0 */
{
    "bookTitle" : "HTML",
    "bookOrder" : 500,
    "_id" : ObjectId("530dea1d2dbf280000533b60"),
    "bookChapters" : [ 
        {
            "chapterTitle" : "chapterTitle",
            "chapterIntro" : "ChapterIntro",
            "chapterOrder" : 500,
            "_id" : ObjectId("530dea1d2dbf280000533b61"),
            "chapterArticles" : [ 
                {
                    "articleTitle" : "articleTitle",
                    "articleIntro" : "articleIntro",
                    "articleOrder" : 500,
                    "_id" : ObjectId("530dea1d2dbf280000533b62"),
                    "articleHeadings" : [ 
                        {
                            "headingTitle" : "headingTitle",
                            "headingOrder" : 500,
                            "_id" : ObjectId("530dea1d2dbf280000533b63")
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "__v" : 0
}
```

To .find() the value of the deeply embedded field "headingTitle" i have to use this query:

```
/*
 db.bookcollections.findOne({"bookChapters.chapterArticles.articleHeadings.headingTitle":"headingTitle"}, {"bookChapters.chapterArticles.articleHeadings.headingTitle":1}).bookChapters[0].chapterArticles[0].articleHeadings[0].headingTitle

*/
```

Concerning best practices:

1. Isn't this very verbose?
2. Is this correct usage?
3. Do i have to rethink the structure of my document?

Comment: At first I would simplify names, to get query ie. `chapters.articles.headings.title`. in short, you have redundand field names.

Comment: good thinking, thx... i will change that soon...

Comment: Keep in mind that you are **really** not asking a programming question here. But are asking for opinions or otherwise making commentary. Perhaps try an re-phrase in the form of a specific question.

Comment: Hi, thx for you concern. I'm not asking for opinions, i'm asking for best practices. I do believe this to be a real programming question.